# What part of speech is "doing" in "...worked his whole life doing a job..."?

Tags: gerunds, parts-of-speech, participles

> His father said he had worked his whole life doing a job he didn't really enjoy.

is the word "doing" a gerund? if yes/no could someone please explain more.

Answer (score 1):

It is a participle modifier. It describes the type of work.

"Gerunds" are present participles that could be replaced by a noun. In practice the difference between a gerund and a participle isn't clear, and the two categories are often merged into one.